# Как в Python написать декоратор, чтобы объединить логику двух функций?

Tags: python, декоратор

Это отвлеченный пример, который описывает задачу, над которой работаю. У меня есть функция `func_one` с определенной логикой. Я написал вторую функцию `func_two`, которая часть кода берет из первой функции, чтобы затем на его основе продолжить свои вычисления.

Я бы не хотел повторять код первой функции во второй. Мне показалось, что с помощью декоратора проблему можно решить: **логику первой функции реализовать во второй, не прибегая к дублированию скрипта**. Однако правильно написать декоратор не вышло: два аргумента, как в приводимом ниже случае, излишни (интерпретатор ожидает один). Но как еще "сшить" обе функции  через обертку, не знаю.

Код:

```
import numpy as np

# первая функция
def func_one(order):
    a = np.sin(x)/2
    return a

# вариант обертки (ошибочный)
def wrap_polynomial(func_one, func_two):
    def wrapper(order):
        request = func_one()
        res = func_two()
        print('Переменная b:\n', res)
    return wrapper

# вторая функция 
@wrap_polynomial
def func_two(order):
    b = a + np.cos(x) 
    return b
```

Comment: Вам нужна сумма функций? Композиция функций?

Comment: Композиция, полагаю. 
В оригинале первая функция дает таблицу с колонками, вторая добавляет новые колонки (рассчитав их на основе первых) и вычитает значения - из одних колонок другие

Comment: Тогда вам не нужен декоратор. Композиция реализуется вложенным вызовом: `def h(x): return g(f(x))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения вашей задачи декоратор **не нужен**.

Можно ограничиться обыкновенным вызовом первой функции внутри второй и затем использовать ее результат, либо, как написали в комментариях, использовать композицию при помощи вложенного вызова.

Но в образовательных целях расскажу вам о том, почему у вас не получилось создать декоратор:

1. Декоратор должен принимать один аргумент, только ту функцию, которую он декорирует, а не две.

   Если вы дополнительно хотите опционально принимать ту функцию, которая будет предварительно выполняться, то для этого нужно сделать еще одну обертку, это называется декоратор с пробросом аргумента.
2. Обычно в декораторе не указывают конкретные аргументы, а пишут `*args, **kwrags`, чтобы пробросить все аргументы в декорируемую функцию независимо от их количества.
3. Внутри функции `wrapper` вы должны возвращать результат выполнения той функции, которая декорируется, иначе `return` в функции `func_two` не будет работать и результатом всегда будет `None`.

Выглядеть это должно примерно следующим образом:

```
import numpy as np

def func_one(x):
    a = np.sin(x) / 2
    return a

def wrap_polynomial(func_one=None):
    def decorator(func_two):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            intermediate_result = func_one(*args, **kwargs)
            print('Предварительное значение: ', intermediate_result)
            result = func_two(arg=intermediate_result, **kwargs)
            return result
        return wrapper
    return decorator


@wrap_polynomial(func_one=func_one)
def func_two(arg=None):
    print('Получен аргумент: ', arg)
    b = np.cos(arg)
    return b

print(func_two(1))
```

Результат:

> ```
> Предварительное значение: 0.42073549240394825
> Получен аргумент: 0.42073549240394825
> 0.9127887886561931
> ```

Comment: Зачем эти сложности с декоратором? Если `func_two` всегда делает `func_one` первым делом, то нужно ее просто вызвать в самом начале.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA думаю, в случае если предварительно вызываемая функция заранее не известна, то такое решение - тоже допустимо. Посчитал, что если бы она была всегда одинаковой, то действительно простой вызов функции решал бы проблему)

Comment: Если фукция заранее неизвестна, то что вы передадите в декоратор? :) И потом, какой контракт у `func_two`? Что она делает? Т.е. является ли частью ее обязанностей делать то, что реализовано в `func_one` или нет? Если да, то простой вызов лучше. Если нет - то и декоратор тут не к месту.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA да, тут уже трудно не согласиться, что-то упустил это из виду) спасибо! пускай тогда останется с целью того, чтобы автор посмотрел свои ошибки при создании декоратора, раз в целом вопрос на эту тематику)

Comment: @Roman-Stop RU aggression in UA, допустим, я вызываю функцию `func_one`, находясь во второй функции `func_two`. И если мне надо из первой брать не просто возвращаемую целиком таблицу, а один из списков, формирующих один из столбцов таблицы `Pandas` (список лежит в своей переменной): мне в таком случае доставать эту переменную (и список) через `func_one.list` ?

Comment: В этом новом примере много непонятного. Что возвращает `func_one`? Что значит 'список лежит в своей переменной'? Это локальная переменная в func_one?

Comment: @Roman-Stop RU aggression in UA, `func_one` возвращает датафрейм с колонками, где в каждый столбец передано по переменной типа `list`. и да - это локальные переменные `func_one`, как и другие переменные, которые мне требуется использовать в `func_two`, хотя рассчитаны они в `func_one`.